# React Native 'Unordered'-style List

Tags: react-native

How would one go about creating a list in React Native that looked similar to an unordered list (`<ul>`) in HTML? Does it require a flex based layout with two `View`s (one to contain the 'bullet' & the other the list item text) or is their an easier, less cumbersome way?

Comment: I think you would have manually write the flex based layout. Android/iOS provide no native support for <ul> equivalent list.

Comment: You can use this ready made component 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70830102/6665568

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Potentially, the easiest way would be just to use a unicode character for the bullet.  That way you don't have wrap a bunch of components together.

For example, the following component that uses a `ListView` (see the `renderRow` function for the bullet):

```js
class TestProject extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }).cloneWithRows(['string1', 'string2', 'string3']),
    };
  }

  renderRow(data) {
    return (
      <Text>{`\u2022 ${data}`}</Text>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        style={{margin: 40}}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

If you need to keep the text from wrapping around the bullet, you will actually need to use multiple components, as suggested in the question.  For example:

```
renderRow(data) {
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Text>{'\u2022'}</Text>
      <Text style={{flex: 1, paddingLeft: 5}}>{data}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach, but in terms of formatting, it does not accomplish what a HTML equivalent `<ul>` accomplishes, preventing the list item contents from wrapping beneath the bullet. Take a look at the code you provided here: https://rnplay.org/apps/M5zw5Q -- how could this be modified to prevent the text from wrapping?

Comment: You actually will need to use multiple components, in that case.  I've updated my answer with a minimal example.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this component for this purpose : Enjoy

```js
export const UnorderedList = ({texts}: {texts: string[]}) => {
  return (
    <Column>
      {texts.map((t, index) => (
        <Row key={index}>
          <Column
            style={{
              alignSelf: 'flex-start',
              justifyContent: 'flex-start',
              marginRight: 12,
              transform: [{scale: 2.5}],
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                justifyContent: 'flex-start',
              }}>
              {'\u2022'}
            </Text>
          </Column>
          <Column>
            <Text>{t}</Text>
          </Column>
        </Row>
      ))}
    </Column>
  );
};


const Column = ({children,style})=>{
   return <View
      style={[{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'},style]}>
      {children}
    </View>
}

const Row = ({children,style})=>{
   return <View
      style={[{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'},style]}>
      {children}
    </View>
}
```

Comment: The styling on this was helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Consider you a list called "ListItems", holding all the content you want in the unordered list, we can approach this problem as follows. This will give you the required format.

```
       <View>
          {ListItems.map(
            (item, index) => (
              <Text>
                {"\u2B24" + " "}
                {item}
              </Text>
            )
          )}
        </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use the [`@jsamr/react-native-li`](https://github.com/jsamr/react-native-li/tree/master/packages/react-native-li#readme) library which is serving this exact purpose.

### Features

- Supports over 40 ordered and unordered pre-defined markers
- Easy to define new markers with a JS-based [CSS Counter Styles Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-counter-styles-3) API
- Right-to-left mode

### Install

```
npm add --save @jsamr/react-native-li @jsamr/counter-style
```

### Usage

Children of the `MarkedList` component will be wrapped in a marked view:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import disc from '@jsamr/counter-style/presets/disc';
import MarkedList from '@jsamr/react-native-li';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <MarkedList counterRenderer={disc}>
        {[...Array(100).keys()].map((index) => (
          <Text key={index} style={{ flexShrink: 1 }}>
            The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)
            develops international standards
            for the web and HTML, CSS, and more.
          </Text>
        ))}
      </MarkedList>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

> **Remark**: “Marker” is CSS terminology for the ordered prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using a View, set it with a Text component inside a View with `flexDirection: 'row'`

```
<View style={{height:5, width: 5, backgroundColor: '#000', borderRadius: 20}} />
```

if you use Unicode, you won't be able to change the size or color, so I believe it would be better to use it like this